# Pump Probe Spectroscopy Zero Delay

Tags: optics, experimental-physics, laser, non-linear-optics

I am setting up a Non Degenerate Pump Probe Experimental Setup, in my lab, as part of my Master's Project. Due to the constraints of the way the lasers have been set up in the lab, I am unable to match the path length of the Pump and Probe sources. Instead what I am trying to do, is ensure that there is spatial and temporal overlap of pump and probe signals.

Is there any procedure for ensuring that both the pulses from the pump and probe are overlapping completely at zero delay between the signals, if not how to rectify it?

Comment: One standard way is to use a nonlinear crystal and measure second harmonic generation vs relative delay. The peak is zero delay.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on why we have this kind of observation?

Comment: Because SHG is a strong function of intensity.